# Cannot Read Property "toString" of Undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, tostring

I am attempting to take an array of numbers, convert them to strings (and then a single string) so that I can easily store multiple values in a key:value db (5 2 digit numbers -> one 10 digit number).
I have an array of 5 numbers, a function with a for loop inside that I want to look at array[i], pull out the number, and convert it to a string.

```
var index1 = [0, 4, 6, 2, 11]

// merge indexes into one number - to be stored in db - take apart when called
function storeVal() {
  let valueArray = []
  for(i = 0; i <= index1.length; i++) {
    let num = index1[i].toString()
    if  (num.length < 2) {
      let newString = '0' + num
      valueArray.push(newString)
    } else {
      valueArray.push(num)
    }
  }
  return valueArray
}
console.log(storeVal())
```

This code gave me an error "Cannot Read Property "toString" of Undefined ".
When I change the index1[i] line it doesn't throw the error, but doesn't allow me to use the right values.

Comment: The last `i` is 5, and the last index of the array is 4

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you are running the loop till it is less than **or equal** to the size of array index1.

To fix this, you can change the part of the for loop

```
for(i = 0; i <= index1.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < index1.length; i++) {
```